# Processing email errors to disable sending

Tags: php, email

Is there a way to intercept email replies with PHP? I'd like to process emails saying that a mailbox is unavailable to disable sending for any user accounts associated with a failing address.

Comment: You can watch the mailbox with a PHP script (http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) on a regular cron job and reply to any emails that come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question provides a couple of techniques for doing that. [E-mail verification through e-mail & PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333615/e-mail-verification-through-e-mail-php)